# How to indent print output produced by a for-loop in Python?

Tags: python

My code is something like this.

```py
jlist = [1]

for j in jlist:

   print(f'working on section {j}')

   ilist = [1,2]

   for i in ilist:

      classObject.method(i)
```

which produce the output

```
working on section 1

result from item 1
result from item 2
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
working on section 1

   result from item 1
   result from item 2
```

I would prefer not to have to modify the class methods.

Thanks

Comment: You can simply add spaces to your statement, right?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Your current example is missing some declarations.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an indent by printing it without a newline:

```
for i in ilist:
    print('    ', end='', flush=True)
```

I also added `flush=True` to ensure it gets printed before `classObject.method(i)`

I'm assuming the extra newline in your output is there by accident. If not, you'd need to intercept `sys.stdout` and this would get way more complicated.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I tried it with `flush=False`, too. The extra newline is by mistake, but the print output of `classObject.method()` is multiline.

Comment: I'm not a CS expert, but from what I understand, before things are printed they go through something like `sys.stdout`. If I could capture all of the strings produced by the for-loop then I could just indent them with a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in ilist:
    print('\t' + classObject.method(i))
```

Comment: This most likely will print "None". The OP left out some details, but I think `classObject.method(i))` has a `print()` call and no return.

Comment: It would great if you can explain why your code sample is the solution. Instead of just dropping some lines of code, giving context and explanation does help everone to understand your solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice there can be a return too, we are not sure.

Comment: @Surya exactly. We need clarification before this can be a valid answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is correct, the class method calls the print function, so I can't prefix its output with a `\t`.

Comment: @HermanAutore then why don't you try adding '\t' to the print function called by class method

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your method will always print only one line, then use the code from the answer of @wjandrea.

If there could be multiple usages of `print` in your method, it gets a little bit more complicated. But we can achieve the task by temporarily replacing `print` with an own version.

Let's use a simple example.

```
def do_something(value):
    print(f'The value: {value}')

print('HEADER')
for item in ['Monty', 'Python']:
    do_something(item)
print('FOOTER')
```

This will output

```
HEADER
The value: Monty
The value: Python
FOOTER
```

Now we add an own function `print_indented` that will replace the builtin `print` function. In the new function we call the builtin `print`, but we add two spaces before the first value (if it exists).

```
def print_indented(*args, **kwargs):
    if not args:
        __builtins__.print()
    else:
        __builtins__.print('  ' + args[0], args[1:], kwargs)
```

Before we call `do_something` we replace `print` with our function and set it back after the call.

```
def print_indented(*args, **kwargs):
    if not args:
        __builtins__.print()
    else:
        __builtins__.print('  ' + args[0], args[1:], kwargs)

def do_something(value):
    print(f'The value: {value}')

print('HEADER')
for item in ['Monty', 'Python']:
    print = print_indented
    do_something(item)
    print = __builtins__.print
print('FOOTER')
```

Result

```
HEADER
  The value: Monty
  The value: Python
FOOTER
```

Note: This is a simple approach. There are ways to optimize this with context managers and decorators.

---

To elaborate on the usage of `__builtins__.print`: Why don't we just use `print` in the function `print_indented`? Before we entered the function `print_indented` we replaced `print` with exactly this function. This would mean, that the function would call itself ... and again and again and again until we get a `RecursionError`. So with `__builtins__.print` we make sure we use the `print` provided by the Python core.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to add the indentation directly to `print()`. From comments, this is inside the `classObject.method(i)` calls:

```
print('    ', ...)
```

where `...` is what you are already printing.